# creating bitmap image from a hexadecimal data

Tags: c, bitmapimage

Following array is a hexadecimal array of a monochrome bitmap image:

```
const unsigned char bill[]    
{    0xFF,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
0xFF,0xFF,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
};
```

How to create a bit map image from this hexadecimal array using c program and how to create a hexadecimal array from a bitmap image?
i searched on internet. but whatever information i got was above my head. i dont know anything about bitmap image. thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to know the image dimensions and the format.  RGB 24bit, 32 bit ARGB, 32 bit RGBA, RGB 565,....?

Comment: its a monochrome printer. image is monochrome.

Comment: @spartygw - You can get the dimensions by reading and parsing the bitmap file header. Here is an example: http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/beginnercpp/361125/361125/loading-a-bitmap-image-in-c/

Comment: @sakshi - It might help to have some understanding about the file format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: @KristerAndersson he doesn't have a bitmap header to parse.  He's got an array of hex values.

Comment: yeah spartygw i dont have any bitmap header :( this hexadecimal array came as a sample. and what i know is its a monochrome image.

Comment: That is not going to be a very interesting image.  Looks like a few blocks of continuous color and a bit of speckle at the beginning from a quick glance at the data.  Assuming 0x00 is black and 0xFF is white.  Doesn't appear to be 1 bit per pixel as I would expect from a monochrome image.  It might be 8-bit color indexed with 0xFF pointing to white, but hard to say.

Comment: @michael: sorry... i picked just 2 lines from the array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Donwload library for operating with bitmap images (eg. this: https://code.google.com/p/libbmp/). Than fill image using this library ans store it. If you want to load image, than open image with libarary and fill you array.

As for image dimensions. You can try all possible combinations that in mul gives you array size `width * height = array size` (neither of dimension wont imho be 1).